# GDIIndexBar как изменить цвет выбранной буквы?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Использую бибилиотеку https://github.com/gdavis/GDIIndexBar, возможно ли изменить цвет только выбранной буквы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, воспользовался другой библиотекой https://github.com/AllinMobile/AIMTableViewIndexBar.